# File.AppendAllText Default Encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

Existing code is calling the `File.AppendAllText(filename, text)` overload to save text to a file.

I need to be able to specify encoding without breaking backwards compatibility.  If I was to use the `File.AppendAllText(filename, text, encoding)` overload which encoding would I need to specify to ensure that files were created in exactly the same way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two arguments overload of [AppendAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) ends up calling the internal method `File.InternalAppendAllText()` using an UTF-8 encoding without BOM:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static void AppendAllText(string path, string contents)
{
    if (path == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    }
    if (path.Length == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyPath"));
    }
    File.InternalAppendAllText(path, contents, StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM);
}
```

Therefore, you can write:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

File.AppendAllText(filename, text, new UTF8Encoding(false, true));
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at the sources for File.AppenAllText reveals the following implementation:

```
public static void AppendAllText(string path, string contents)
{
  // Removed some checks
  File.InternalAppendAllText(path, contents, StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM);
}

internal static Encoding UTF8NoBOM
{
  get
  {
    if (StreamWriter._UTF8NoBOM == null)
    {
      StreamWriter._UTF8NoBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
    }
    return StreamWriter._UTF8NoBOM;
  }
}
```

So it looks like you want to pass an instance of UTF8Encoding without the UTF8 header bytes.